# Select previous element in CSS

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS previous sibling selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector)

I'm exploring CSS3 and all I can do with only pure HTML/CSS3, and I've come across a little problem I can't find a solution to.

I have a few `<div>`s with the style `float:left;`. When I hover on the first one, I want to apply some CSS to the second one. Pretty easy, I just use `div.div1:hover + div` and it's all good. But what about the other way around? If I hover the second `<div>`, how can I apply some CSS to the first `<div>`?

I can use any CSS, I don't really care about browser compatibility, I just want to explore how far I can go with pure CSS3.

Comment: Nope, there's no way for CSS to look backwards. You either need to use JavaScript DOM manipulation or rearrange your floating elements (try floating something right instead?) so they're in the desired order.

Comment: You have no idea how many times this question has been asked here.